# How to effectively get the N lowest values from the collection (Top N) in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

How to effectively get the N lowest values from the collection (Top N) in Kotlin?

Is there any other way besides `collectionOrSequence.sortedby{it.value}.take(n)`?

Assume I have a collection with +100500 elements and I need to found 10 lowest. I'm  afraid that the `sortedby` will create new temporary collection which later will take only 10 items.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could keep a list of the n smallest elements and just update it on demand, e.g.

```
fun <T : Comparable<T>> top(n: Int, collection: Iterable<T>): List<T> {
    return collection.fold(ArrayList<T>()) { topList, candidate ->
        if (topList.size < n || candidate < topList.last()) {
            // ideally insert at the right place
            topList.add(candidate)
            topList.sort()
            // trim to size
            if (topList.size > n)
                topList.removeAt(n)
        }
        topList
    }
}
```

That way you only compare the current element of your list once to the largest element of the top n elements which would usually be faster than sorting the entire list https://pl.kotl.in/SyQPtDTcQ

Comment: can you explain what does collection.fold do ?

Comment: @AngelKoh it applies every element of the list to a thing and uses the result for the next element. Here it tries to insert each element into the initially emtpy Arraylist<T> https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/fold.html a bit similar to reduce

Comment: Thanks. I thought so. But I was so hoping that the standard library already has.

Answer (score 4):

If you're running on the JVM, you could use Guava's [`Comparators.least(int, Comparator)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Comparators.html#least-int-java.util.Comparator-), which uses a more efficient algorithm than any of these suggestions, taking O(n + k log k) time and O(k) memory to find the lowest k elements in a collection of size n, as opposed to zapl's algorithm (O(nk log k)) or Lior's (O(nk)).

Answer (score 1):

You have more to worry about.

- `collectionOrSequence.sortedby{it.value}` runs `java.util.Arrays.sort`, that will run timSort (or mergeSort if requested).
- [timSort](https://hackernoon.com/timsort-the-fastest-sorting-algorithm-youve-never-heard-of-36b28417f399) is great, but usually ends by n*log(n) operations, which is much more than the O(n) of copying the array.
- Each of the O(n*log.n) operations will run a function (the lambda you provided, `{it.value}`) --> an additional meaningful overhead.
- Lastly, `java.util.Arrays.sort` will convert the collection to Array and back to a List - 2 additional conversions (which you wanted to avoid, but this is secondary)

The efficient way to do it is probably:

1. `map` the values for comparison into a list: O(n) conversions (once per element) rather than O(n*log.n) or more.
2. Iterate over the list (or Array) created to collect the *N* smallest elements in one pass

   - Keep a list of *N* smallest elements found so far and their index on the original list. If it is small (e.g. 10 items) - `mutableList` is a good fit.
   - Keep a variable holding the max value for the small element list.
   - When iterating over the original collection, compare the current element on the original list against the max value of the small values list. If smaller than it - replace it in the "small list" and find the updated max value in it.
3. Use the indexes from the "small list" to extract the 10 smallest elements of the original list.

That would allow you to go from O(n*log.n) to O(n).

Of course, if time is critical - it is always best to benchmark the specific case.

If you managed, on the first step, to extract primitives for the basis of comparison (e.g. `int` or `long`) - that would be even more efficient.

Comment: Note that the "replace it in the small list" step takes O(k), where k=10 in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest implementing your own sort method based on a typical quickSort algorithm(in descending order, and take the first N elements), if the collection has 1k+ values spread randomly.